# Sql query value duplication

Tags: sql

Let's have a query

```
SELECT `name`, `companyid`
  FROM `users`
```

where the result could be

```
Peter   | 1
Michael | 1
Tom     | 2
John    | 2
Ian     | 4
```

Is it possible to create a query result where for each unique `companyid` value would be added a row

```
System  | <current companyId>
```

so the result would be

```
Peter   | 1
Michael | 1
System  | 1
Tom     | 2
John    | 2
System  | 2
Ian     | 4
System  | 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
( 
  SELECT name,companyid FROM users
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT 'System', companyid FROM users
)
ORDER BY companyid
```

Comment: would you not need to use a "group by companyid"  clause?

Comment: no the second select is marked as DISTINCT

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, this would work:

```
select *
from
(
    select name, companyid
    from users

    union all

    select distinct 'System', companyid
    from users
)a
order by companyid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name,companyid FROM users
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT 'System' as name, companyid 
  FROM users
  GROUP BY companyid
)
```

Should do it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

First some test data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(name VARCHAR(100),companyId INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl (name,companyId)
VALUES
    ('Peter',1),
    ('Michael',1),
    ('Tom',2),
    ('Ian',4)
```

Then the query like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY companyId ORDER BY name) RowNbr,
        tbl.companyId,
        'System' AS name
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT
    tbl.name,
    tbl.companyId
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT
    CTE.name,
    CTE.companyId
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, companyid
  FROM users
UNION
SELECT 'System' AS name, companyid
  FROM users;
```